# Как написать регулярку, которая будет доставать id телеграмма

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

К примеру, у меня есть строка "Мой телеграмм: @qw12ggg, мой viber: @qw12ggg". Нужно написать регулярку, которая будет доставать только телеграмм, при этом он сам может быть написан, как "телега", "telegram" и тд

Comment: Какие конкретно у вас возникли трудности?

Answer (score 4):

Можно вот так:

```
(teleg|телег).+?(@\w+)
```

Первая группа `(teleg|телег)` подставляет варианты написание, `.+?` подбирает несколько любых символов после первой группы, а вторая группа вот она: `(@\w+)`, это то, что вам нужно, строка вида: `@qw12ggg`.

[Ссылка](https://regex101.com/r/6Sh1pl/1)